Class HtmlRenderer does not exist
can anybody help? I use magento 2.3.7 , php 7.4  and i can not do seup:di:compile
I tried to find the error, but it seems to be some file missing....Thanks.
[ReflectionException]                                                             
  Class Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRender\HtmlRenderer does not exist  
                                                                                    

Exception trace:
  at /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:35
 ReflectionParameter->getClass() at /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:35
 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() at /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassReaderDecorator.php:35
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassReaderDecorator->getConstructor() at /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/Decorator/Area.php:55
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\Decorator\Area->getList() at /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Area.php:114
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\Area->getDefinitionsCollection() at /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Area.php:87
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\Area->doOperation() at /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php:56
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() at /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php:206
 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() at /var/www/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1021
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:275
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:115
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:149
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/magento2/bin/magento:23

I already tried the basic things, like removing generated files, cleaning and flushing cache as well upgrading before do setup:di:compile.

Try the following steps.
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/


Thanks for the help, but i continue to have the same error. I also tried to change getClass() in ClassReader.php for the new version of magento 2 from magento/framework, but the error continues.  I lost almost a week trying to solve this. I think i will try to reinstall everything again in other server. Thanks again.

Have you try to run compilation command one's?

Which one? The problem happens when I try to run setup:di:compile. It does not complete because of this error.

Try to disable all third party extension and then check.

Hello guys, I resintalled and copied all magento 2 files again, and it worked.  It was probably a third party extension that I tried to upgrade but returned for the old one in the end. I noticed after installing, when setup:upgrade, it gave an error of reference in columns in the same table of the extension. I removed the old one, but the columns in the database remained. Thanks to you all.
